# FME - Copying a full list of 'user attributes'

Tags: postgis, fme-form

I'm new to FME, so just getting used to the interface.

I've loaded a template .fmw which has given me a full process, including an example 'Writer'. This writer is no use to me, and as I can't change it to PostGIS, I've created a new writer for the output. However, there is a really long list of attributes that need to be duplicated into the new writer.

Does anyone have any idea if there is a quick way to copy across multiple attributes from one writer to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your new writer then Choose Copy from Feature type context menu and then choose your attribute writer..I hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Venug, but you have misunderstood my question. I want to copy the list of attributes from another writer that has already been set up with the correct list of attributes. There are a lot of them so I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Right click on your new writer then Choose Copy from Feature type context menu and then choose your attribute writer..I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 4):

You can open the properties dialog (for the original writer) and use the Writer option there to move that table from one writer to the other. That way you don't have to copy from one table to another.

[image]

As the above screenshot shows, it doesn't even need to be the same format. FME will automatically adjust the data types to match the new format.

However, since you're using PostGIS, it's possible that the table exists already in that database. If so, use Writers > Import Feature Types from the menubar to select tables from that database to add to the workspace as table definitions. That way you get it directly from the database and there is no risk of a typo or other issue.

You'll find more info on all of these techniques in chapter 4 of the [basic training manual for FME](https://www.gitbook.com/book/safe-software/fme-desktop-basic-training-2016/details)

Comment: What? Safe published training manuals?  Nice.

Comment: Oh yes. Search on GitBook (and GitHub). There are Basic Desktop, Advanced Desktop, and Server Authoring manuals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mark, but selecting the existing writer as shown in your screenshot does not have the desired affect of adding the list of copying across the list of attributes. Good tip on the possibility of using an existing table in PostGIS, but in this case I am creating a new table.